# Twitter V2 API for tracking Likes

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to track engagements for a tweet that I made through API.

I am tracking the engagements for this tweet with the `tweetID` given to me when making the tweet.

I am getting this error when I'm trying to track the engagement for the tweet ID:

```
{
“client_id”: “2xxxx7492”,

“detail”: “When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.”,

“registration_url”: “/en/docs/projects/overview”,

“title”: “Client Forbidden”,

“required_enrollment”: “Appropriate Level of API Access”,

“reason”: “client-not-enrolled”,

“type”: “2/problems/client-forbidden”
}
```

I am using this end point: tweets/xxxxxx/liking_users

Bearer token was generated with these scopes: `tweet.read users.read`, `like.read`.

Need some help with figuring out this issue please.